# How to determine object orientation in binary image? (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am supposed to determine the direction a windmill is facing from aerial images (with respect to True North - 0 to 359 degrees).

My question is, how can I determine the correct direction of the windmill and calculate its angle relative to the y-axis? Thanks!

Comment: You already have the box points, can you use the points to get the angle of the box?

Comment: Yes, but the biggest issue is figuring out if the windmill is pointing (in this case) to the upper-left (correct) or bottom-right (incorrect).

Comment: calculaing that blobs centroid's position in the bounding box should give you the direction... how long have you been thinking about this? 2 minutes?

Comment: @Piglet Due to noise (shadows etc.), segmented blobs are not always symmetrical like this one, so centroids can be misleading.

Comment: If this image alone is not representative, then maybe you should collate a sample of 10 or so images + corresponding target vector.

Comment: why don't you use the data from the windpark? they know how their mills are oriented. that would be much easier than flying around and doing image processing for every single mill

Comment: I'd say gathering data from the windpark is not exatly obvious (and very off-topic given the question)

Comment: @Piglet that's not very practical and in that case he won't need computer vision to do that which is not what he wants on his project

Comment: @GPhilo in 90% of all questions on image processing here the initial thought is wrong and very often people don't even think of the most obvious things. If I had to do that this would be the first thing I'd try because even if I have to pay for that information it would most likely be cheaper in the long run and more importantly much more accurate and robust.

Comment: @Piglet Still, if the question is about an image processing technique, "just get data somewhere else" is off-topic. It's the OP's judgement, not yours, to decide whether this is for him the most practical solution or not.

Comment: @GPhilo well I only suggested another solution to his problem. sometimes you have to think out of the box.... I'm not quite sure why you have to come around and judge me for that for no reason. bully someone else or get some manners. I don't think the OP needs you to defend his approach. and regarding our comment that it is not very obvious to aks the windpark: many windparks already happily publish power output and all other fancy parameters in real time over the internet. if you like it or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not know if this works in general, but given your sample images I'd find the middle point of the short edges of the bounding box and get two rectangles for the two halves of the big BBox.

I would then compute the sum of the mask pixels in the two separate half-BBoxes, assuming white is 1 and black is 0. Since the white area is bigger on the half of the rectangle where the "front" of the turbine is, pick the direction according to which of the two half-BBoxes has a higher sum

Comment: Nice trick to start with.. However, it depends on how much precision he wants, because the direction of the rectangle depends on the color of the ground and the thresholding (binarization)

Comment: Indeed, but given what he presents as example, that' the best I can suggest. His processing is a chain of error-adding operations: segmentation of the turbine, bounding-box estimation and then direction estimation. Of these, the first two operations are more critical than the third, because with a good bounding box the choice of direction boils down to a binary choice